# Ejecutar dos consultas sql en la misma funcion

Tags: php, email

Estoy tratando de obtener los emails de dos tablas diferentes, con el fin de de reunirlos en un solo array para enviar mensajes masivos a todos los suscriptores.

No se si pueda hacerlo de esta manera pero lo que hice en el controller fue enviarle el nombre de dos tablas a el modelo así:

```
static public function mensajesMasivosController(){

        if(isset($_POST["tituloMasivoEs"])){

            $respuesta =  MensajesModelEs::seleccionarEmailSuscriptores("suscriptorespanol");

            $respuesta .= MensajesModelEs::seleccionarEmailSuscriptores("suscriptorform");


        }
    }
```

Ahora esto puse en el model

```
static public function seleccionarEmailSuscriptores($tabla){

    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT email FROM $tabla");

    $stmt .= Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT email FROM $tabla");
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt -> fetchAll();

    $stmt -> close();


}
```

Ahora obtengo este error:

Recoverable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string

que podria hacer para seleccionar info de dos tablas al mismo tiempo?

Gracias por su respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviamente no. El punto `.` es para concatenar string  no para unir arrays. Para conseguir lo que deseas tienes 2 opciones desde mi punto de vista, utilizar `UNION` de SQL o hacer un merge de los resultados con array_merge().

Ejemplo UNION, pasas los 2 nombres de la tabla a la función:

```
static public function seleccionarEmailSuscriptores($tabla, $tabla2)
{
    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT email FROM $tabla UNION SELECT email FROM $tabla2");

    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt -> fetchAll();
}
```

Al llamar al método:

```
$respuesta =  MensajesModelEs::seleccionarEmailSuscriptores("suscriptorespanol", "suscriptorform");
```

Ejemplo con array_merge()

En el método solo necesitas hacer una consulta:

```
static public function seleccionarEmailSuscriptores($tabla)
{
    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT email FROM $tabla");

    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt -> fetchAll();
}
```

Al llamar al método:

```
$respuesta =  MensajesModelEs::seleccionarEmailSuscriptores("suscriptorespanol");
$respuesta2 =  MensajesModelEs::seleccionarEmailSuscriptores("suscriptorform");
// unimos los resultados 
$result = array_merge($respuesta, $respuesta2);
```